# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string

Tags: arrays

Alright, so basically, I am trying to write a simple program. The purpose is that it reads a file (the file is a set of numbers that would fill a 401 by 401 table) and then writes the data into an array and prints the array to the console. This is going ot be used later to find specific numbers, so like I will write code to find the highest and lowest numbers in the array etc. I don't know how yet, but I haven't got the program working yet. Every time I run this program, the exact error I get is as follows.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "363.0 360.0 354.0 349.0 343.0 339.0 333.0 319.0 324.0 325.0 324.0 317.0 317.0 322.0 322.0 320.0 315.0 314.0 313.0 311.0 309.0 308.0 315.0 320.0 326.0 332.0 336.0 341.0 346.0 350.0 353.0 353.0 352.0 351.0 352.0 353.0 351.0 350.0 346.0 339.0 338.0 349.0 354.0 357.0 360.0 366.0 371.0 377.0 383.0 387.0 393.0 398.0 402.0 409.0 414.0 419.0 425.0 432.0 439.0 442.0 444.0 446.0 448.0 450.0 453.0 457.0 460.0 460.0 462.0 464.0 465.0 466.0 467.0 467.0 469.0 470.0 471.0 470.0 470.0 470.0 470.0 477.0 479.0 480.0 486.0 490.0 492.0 495.0 497.0 496.0 499.0 499.0 500.0 500.0 499.0 499.0 499.0 500.0 500.0 497.0 494.0 491.0 488.0 487.0 485.0 490.0 490.0 488.0 484.0 482.0 481.0 478.0 474.0 471.0 466.0 461.0 454.0 449.0 443.0 436.0 432.0 422.0 410.0 397.0 389.0 381.0 375.0 365.0 340.0 318.0 289.0 283.0 276.0 266.0 255.0 241.0 235.0 233.0 234.0 235.0 235.0 239.0 257.0 281.0 302.0 321.0 330.0 337.0 354.0 373.0 383.0 389.0 401.0 410.0 413.0 403.0 389.0 381.0 373.0 363.0 351.0 343.0 335.0 328.0 322.0 314.0 306.0 298.0 293.0 285.0 275.0 270.0 276.0 283.0 286.0 286.0 285.0 283.0 283.0 283.0 279.0 274.0 270.0 264.0 255.0 245.0 239.0 238.0 238.0 239.0 240.0 249.0 256.0 262.0 268.0 272.0 275.0 276.0 275.0 273.0 271.0 269.0 269.0 271.0 274.0 276.0 279.0 283.0 289.0 293.0 294.0 295.0 295.0 297.0 307.0 312.0 314.0 314.0 314.0 313.0 312.0 310.0 307.0 305.0 304.0 303.0 304.0 299.0 291.0 308.0 325.0 335.0 344.0 351.0 358.0 361.0 366.0 370.0 379.0 382.0 386.0 389.0 391.0 391.0 390.0 390.0 393.0 395.0 397.0 402.0 408.0 412.0 413.0 414.0 415.0 415.0 416.0 416.0 416.0 415.0 415.0 414.0 413.0 411.0 410.0 408.0 407.0 407.0 406.0 404.0 402.0 400.0 394.0 375.0 379.0 390.0 394.0 397.0 397.0 397.0 397.0 402.0 405.0 407.0 407.0 412.0 417.0 423.0 428.0 441.0 448.0 451.0 453.0 457.0 458.0 459.0 460.0 460.0 460.0 458.0 456.0 455.0 454.0 455.0 455.0 455.0 454.0 452.0 452.0 451.0 450.0 450.0 450.0 450.0 447.0 442.0 440.0 437.0 436.0 436.0 437.0 437.0 437.0 436.0 434.0 429.0 427.0 425.0 422.0 412.0 410.0 415.0 415.0 414.0 413.0 413.0 414.0 411.0 410.0 409.0 408.0 406.0 404.0 402.0 400.0 398.0 395.0 393.0 392.0 389.0 387.0 385.0 384.0 380.0 377.0 376.0 375.0 374.0 372.0 370.0 369.0 367.0 365.0 362.0 355.0 346.0 340.0 334.0 331.0 331.0 330.0 327.0 323.0 322.0 319.0 316.0 315.0 310.0 297.0 289.0 280.0 274.0 274.0 282.0 301.0 320.0 328.0 344.0 352.0 351.0 350.0 346.0 341.0 338.0 333.0 329.0 323.0 318.0 312.0 308.0 304.0"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
    at MultiArray.main(MultiArray.java:19)

Now, here is the code for my program.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;  //importing tools

public class MultiArray {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {

        //variables
        int rows = 401;
        int columns = 401;
        String file = "dmt.asc";

        double dmtData[][] = new double[rows][columns];  //array

        BufferedReader Reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)); //read the file

        //split the numbers and write to array
        for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
            String rowArray [] = Reader.readLine().split("\t");
            for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++){
                dmtData[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(rowArray[j]);
            }
        }

        Reader.close();  //close the reader and the file

        //print out the array
        for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++){
                System.out.println(dmtData[i][j]);
            }
        }

        //code here to find highest number
        System.out.println("The highest peak in this area is: ");

        //code here to find lowest number
        System.out.println("The lowest dip in this area is: ");

    }

}
```

Thanks for any help, I promise once I understand java I'll do my best to answer questions on here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `rowArray[j]`  is returning a proper parsable double value, then you should not have any trouble in your code. See your file whether its seperated by **\t** (tab) and not jus **" "**(whitespace).
Cos I did the same mistake while trying to execute your code and check getting the same exception as told by you..

Comment: The numbers in the file were only separated by 1 space, so in the split, I changed the code from ("\t) just to (" ") and it worked thanks, really appreciate it!

Comment: Ok, so after this worked, I moved onto find the highest and smallest values in the data array. However, now I cannot get that to work xD I added the import java.util.Arrays, and I also tried adding the java.util.*. After this, the code I tried to use is as follows:

Comment: Arrays.sort(dmtData);
  System.out.println("The highest peak in this area is: " + dmtData[dmtData.length-1]);
  System.out.println("The lowest dip in this area is: " + dmtData[0]);